# how to filter the distance between 1 user and a list of sellers in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

hello i am trying to have a page where as soon as a buyer or seller navigates to it calculates the distance between that user and other sellers, i have found the calculation to do it and i  have found out how to calculate it but i want the user to be able to filter the distance but the thing is that the distance is not a column in my table so it gives an error of

```
TypeError at /marketplace/search/
'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: distance
```

here is my code below

```
def calc_dist_fixed(lat_a, long_a, lat_b, long_b):
    """all angles in degrees, result in miles"""
    lat_a = radians(lat_a)
    lat_b = radians(lat_b)
    delta_long = radians(long_a - long_b)
    cos_x = (
        sin(lat_a) * sin(lat_b) +
        cos(lat_a) * cos(lat_b) * cos(delta_long)
        )
    return acos(cos_x) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES


class Listsellers(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Seller_account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SellerAccountSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    def calc_dist(self):
        user = self.request.Users.objects.username
        seller = Users.objects.filter(seller=True)
        lat_a = user.latitude
        long_a = user.longitude
        lat_b = seller.latitude
        long_b = seller.longitude
        distance = calc_dist_fixed(lat_a, long_a, lat_b, long_b)
    filterset_fields = [
        'distance',
        'cuisine',
        'delivers',
    ]
```

is there something i am missing?

EDIT:

here is the selleraccountserializer:

```
class SellerAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Seller_account
        fields = ['image', 'delivers', 'postcode_of_delivery', 'user_id', 'menu_id', 'cuisine']
```

if you need any more data to further understand my question please do not hesitate to ask

Comment: could you please post your `SellerAccountSerializer` and the stack trace for the error.

Comment: @Abhyudai i have added the SellerAccountSerializer

Answer (score 0):

You can extend filters.FilterSet class to write custom filters based on the values you have in your model. Given below is the rough format i could think of, you use the values you have in your model, do calculations on them and then use the results of the calculation to filter out the queryset. The result value doesn't have to be in the queryset originally.

> class Filter_sellers_within_100km(filters.FilterSet):

> ```
> within_100km_distance = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name=seller.latitude,method='filter_100km_distance')
> ```

> ```
> def filter_100km_distance(self, queryset, name, value):
>     return calc_distance <= 100
> ```

Comment: And while using the filter in url, you will have to do something like
...../order/sellers?within_100km_distance=True

This will return the queryset where the distance value is between 0 and 100km

Comment: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#filter-reference

Here are the docs showing multiple examples

Comment: can i use a charfilter where there are options on how far the distance can be. like a normal choices attribute in models

Comment: I think that is not possible.There are very limited options. But you can take care of it. For user end it still can be a fixed distance value and you translate it as a boolean in your url in the backend.

I mean your frontend says 100 km or 200 km, whatever the user selects and if you use the same format as above, it will get you all the sellers that are in 100 km.

Comment: i have tried your answer and i get an error of 


AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'latitude'

and i don't really understand the answer, how does it give the distance if only given a latitude co-ordinate. And another thing i have the location of both the sellers and buyers in one table, i am getting the co-ordinates of the user by using a self.request.Users.username.all, and i am getting the list of sellers by using sell = User.objects.filter(seller-True). will that affect the filter_100km_distance function